# Problema con output via javascript y PHP

Tags: php, javascript

El problema es el siguiente:
Mi salida solo muestra el primer registro de dirección formateada en su salida. Ejemplo de esto seria:

> Salida deseada:
>
> ```
> Registro 1 : Calle LWP 1234, España
> Registro 2 : Calle LWP2 122234, España
> Registro 3 : Calle LW2P2232 122243434, Brasil
> ```
>
> Salida obtenida:
>
> ```
> Registro 1 : Calle LWP 1234, España  
> Registro 2 :  
> Registro 3 :
> ```

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function (e) {
var geocoder;
initialize();
codeLatLng();
function initialize() {

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

function codeLatLng() {

    var input = document.getElementById("latlng").getAttribute('data-geo');
console.log(input);
    var latlngStr = input.split(",", 2);
    var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
    var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({
        'latLng': latlng
    }, function(results, status) {

        document.getElementById("latlng").innerHTML = '' + (results[0].formatted_address); + ''
    });
}

});
</script>
```

Mi PHP

```
<?php foreach($pets as $pet): ?>
<div id="latlng" data-geo="<?php echo $pet['latitud'];?>,<?php echo $pet['longitud'];?>"> </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu error es que solo estas seleccionando un div el primero
cuyo id es `latlng` la solucion es seleccionar todos los que coincidan
con la funcion `document.querySelectorAll()` puedes hacerlo

> nota: te recomiendo el uso de `let` y no de `var` lo explico en esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/232896/por-que-el-indice-de-mi-objeto-se-repite-en-el-ciclo-for-dentro-de-el-evento-loa/232908?noredirect=1#answer-232908)

**correcion:**

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {
var geocoder;
//initialize();
codeLatLng();


function initialize() {

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

function codeLatLng() {

    let input = document.querySelectorAll("#latlng");

    for(let i of input ){
        let inp = i.getAttribute('data-geo');
        let latlngStr = inp.split(",", 2);
        let lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
        let lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
        i.innerText = `${lat} y ${lng}`;
        
        //comentando para que funcione el interactivo sin errores
        /*let latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        geocoder.geocode({
            'latLng': latlng
        }, function(results, status) {

            i.innerText = `${results[0].formatted_address}`;
        });*/

    }
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="latlng" data-geo="51.0899232,5.968358"> </div>

<div id="latlng" data-geo="36.2063155,-113.7499092"> </div>
<div id="latlng" data-geo="34.4099662,86.0203663"> </div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Desafortunadamente el mismo resultado, solo que esta vez en blanco totalmente. De paso me acusa error de sintaxis en el let.
Probé también asi:
<pre>
for(var i=0; i<=results; i++){

       var x = document.getElementById("latlng").innerHTML = '' + (results[i].formatted_address); + ''
}
</pre>

Comment: te lo agrere interactivo para que pruebes su uso! y el error es que me falto un `#` en el `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: vamos bien, ahora si puedo ver listado por cada registro el texto que parece pertenecerle, el problema es que no me arroja sino esto : "results[0].formatted_address)" y no el formato Calle, Numero, Ciudad :(

Comment: eso es un template ya lo corregi!

Comment: Si, lo corregí así: i.innerText = '' + (results[0].formatted_address); + '' }); El tema es el siguiente, sabes porque el ultimo registro no formatea la geolocacion? . Solo arroja -18.4758212 y -70.3062945